# How can find the Fourier Coefficents of this DFT?

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing, fft, dft

I have a data which contains 16 elements:

```
x=[8.57837e-08, 2.07482e-06, 4.43796e-06, 7.66462e-06, 1.10232e-05, 1.35811e-05, 1.27958e-05, 5.94217e-06, 2.49168e-08, -6.58389e-06, -1.30551e-05, -1.345e-05, -1.07471e-05, -7.38637e-06, -4.42876e-06, -1.88811e-06 ];
A = length(x)
```

I do DTFT-DFT like dirac signals:

```
n=0:A;
syms w 
X_w=0;
for i=1:length(x)
   X_w=X_w+x(i)*exp(-j*w*n(i));
end
figure;fplot(angle(X_w),[0 2*pi]),title('DTFT phase graph')
figure;fplot(abs(X_w),[0 2*pi]),title('DTFT amplitude graph')
hold on


%DFT
N=50;
k=0:N-1; 
DFT_X=[]; 
for k=0:N-1
   Xk=0;
   for i=1:length(x)
     Xk=Xk+x(i).*exp(-j*(2*pi/N).*k.*n(i));
   end
   DFT_X=[DFT_X Xk];
 end
 w=2*pi/N*(0:N-1);
 stem(w,abs(DFT_X))`
```

The problem is I want to write this signal with cosinus and sinus components. But I don't really know how can I do.

Thank you all,
Emre.

Answer (score 1):

Direct computation of the Fourier coefficients might be a better option than trying to relate the DFT to the DFS. Looking at the continuous time formulas:

[image]

all you'd need to do is sum the input signal `x` multiplied (element wise) by a cosine over it's domain for the real coefficient and sum the input signal `x` multiplied (element wise) by a sine over its domain for the imaginary coefficients.

Secondly, you could potentially use conjugate symmetry and these formulas to calculate the relationship between your `Xk` and the desired `An` and `Bn` coefficients.

```
Xk = (An-j*Bn)/2
```

and

```
Xk* = (An+j*Bn)/2)
```

Comment: Some additional reference: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16105/the-difference-between-dft-and-dfs
and
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series